# Accessing variable under PHP 7 different?

Tags: php, php-7

This is what i used before:

```
$langs[$language->lang_code]->$fieldname[1]
```

under PHP 7 thats not working, so looks like i must write:

```
$langs[$language->lang_code]->{$fieldname[1]}
```

Is that so?

Comment: Also explained in the manual: http://php.net/migration70.incompatible

Comment: OK, thanks. Did not find anything when searching on that matter.